# asp.net with autofac - all controls on webform are null

Tags: asp.net, null, controls, httphandler, autofac

I'm using autofac with asp.net. In Global.asax I register all my web pages:

```
AssertNotBuilt();
// Register Web Pages
m_builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(AboutPage).Assembly)
  .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IHttpHandler)))
  .AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

m_container = m_builder.Build();
m_wasBuilt = true;
```

Then I use a custom httpHandler to get the current web page:

```
    public class ContextInitializerHttpHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //Get the name of the page requested
            string aspxPage = context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

            if (aspxPage.Contains(".aspx"))
            {
                // Get compiled type by path
                Type webPageBaseType = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(aspxPage).BaseType;

                // Resolve the current page
                Page page = (Page)scope.Resolve(webPageBaseType);

                //process request
                page.ProcessRequest(context);

            }
        }
        public bool IsReusable
        {
        get { return true; } 
        }
  }
```

All works ok, but then when it enters the web page_load, I see that all the asp controls that exist on the page are null. Why are they null and how do I initialize them?

Comment: You may need to clarify a few things here. It appears you're doing some VERY non-standard stuff. The Autofac wiki tells how to properly integrate with web forms (https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AspNetIntegration). You seem to be using a HANDLER to do some work rather than the MODULE integration Autofac provides. How are users accessing your pages? Is every request piped through that handler? What happens if you just "new up" the page rather than resolving it? Still null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The pages that I registered aren't compiled like the pages that I can take from the context in my http handler:

```
string aspxPage = context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
Type webPageBaseType = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(aspxPage);
```

and these are the pages that I need that do hold all the controls. The problem is, I can't register them at my http handler because they are dynamic and look in a form of somewebpage_aspx and the assembly is App_Web_somewebpage.aspx.cdcab7d2.r3x-vs2n, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

So the solution (or hack..) was not to register the web pages, and instead resolve the page controls from the scope:

```
ILifetimeScope scope = IocInitializer.Instance.InitializeCallLifetimeScope();
Type webPageType = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(aspxPage);
Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(webPageType);

foreach (var webPageProperty in webPageType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
{
    if (scope.IsRegistered(webPageProperty.PropertyType))
    {
        var service = scope.Resolve(webPageProperty.PropertyType);
        webPageProperty.SetValue(page, service, null);
    }
}
```